# PyQt multiple lines automation

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am using PyQt4.I have the following lines

```
self.lineEdit_1.setReadOnly(True)
self.lineEdit_2.setReadOnly(True)
self.lineEdit_3.setReadOnly(True)
self.lineEdit_4.setReadOnly(True)
self.lineEdit_5.setReadOnly(True)
self.lineEdit_6.setReadOnly(True)
self.lineEdit_7.setReadOnly(True)
self.lineEdit_8.setReadOnly(True)
self.lineEdit_9.setReadOnly(True)
self.lineEdit_10.setReadOnly(True)
self.lineEdit_11.setReadOnly(True)
self.lineEdit_12.setReadOnly(True)
self.lineEdit_13.setReadOnly(True)
self.lineEdit_14.setReadOnly(True)
```

here is what i tried

```
for i in range(1,15):
    self.lineEdit_+int(1)+.setReadOnly(True)
```

I am getting invalid syntax error.

I am aware that it can be accomplished using eval or exec but i understand that these aren't the advised methods to accomplish what i want.
I want to know if there is any novel and safe way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) for this:

```
for i in range(1, 15):
    getattr(self, 'lineEdit_%s' % i).setReadOnly(True)
```